# RXJS recursively expand a tree

Tags: rxjs

I have a tree of nodes, each time user "expands" a node, an http request is invoked to get it's children.

[image: tree of nodes]

I'm looking for an RXJS pipeline to recursively expand all tree nodes and emit the expanded tree.

( [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-o6wpg6?file=index.ts) )

The way I do it now, is to mutate the source and output the mutated object when done.
Is there a way for me to simplify this hell ? possibly without mutating source .

```
// 'ROOT' nodes
const rootNodes = [{ id: 0, parent: true }, { id: 1000, parent: true }];

// map the root nodes to a recursive function that mutate node and returns its children observables
const getChildrenOfRoot$ = rootNodes.map(node => getChildren(node));

// call the observables, in parallels, when done, print the *** mutated *** source.
forkJoin(...getChildrenOfRoot$).subscribe(() => console.log(rootNodes));


function getChildren(node: Node): Observable<Node[]> {

  return getChildrenFromServer(node.id).pipe(

    // if no children returned, don't continue
    filter((children: Node[]) => !!(children?.length)),

    // mutate argument's .children property with the returned children array.
    tap((children: Node[]) => (node.children = children)),

    mergeMap((children: Node[]) => {
      // mape children to observables returning either their children, or, an empty array, based on 'parent' property.
      const getChildrenOfChildren$ = children.map(c => (c.parent ? getChildren(c) : of([])));

      return forkJoin(...getChildrenOfChildren$);
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR;

[StackBlitz app.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ejgniu?file=index.ts)

---

### Detailed explanation

Since we're dealing with recursion, I thought it would be easier if we started from a base case.
Let's see what we have initially:

```js
const rootNodes = [{ id: 0, parent: true }, { id: 1000, parent: true }];
```

**Assuming** these are the only parents in this tree(i.e their children will **all** be leaf nodes), our problem becomes easier: for each node in the above array, we must **fetch its children** and **add** a **new property** to their nodes, called `children`.
For this, let's create the `processNodes` children:

```js
function processNodes (nodes: Node[]): Observable<Node[]> {
  return nodes.length 
    ? forkJoin(
        nodes.map(node => node.parent ? processNode(node) : of(node))
      )
    : of([]);
}
```

Note that we're also considering the case where the **nodes array** is empty, so, in that case, we simply return an empty array(`of([])`). Let's now focus on this part:

```js
forkJoin(
  nodes.map(node => node.parent ? processNode(node) : of(node))
)
```

If the argument of `processNodes` was:

```js
[{ id: 0, parent: true }, { id: 1000, parent: true }, { id: 7, parent: false }]
```

then the expected output would be:

```js
[
  { id: 0, parent: true, children: [/* ... */] },
  { id: 1000, parent: true, children: [/* ... */] },
  { id: 7, parent: false }
]
```

So, in case a node is a parent, then we have separated logic encapsulated in the `processNode` function:

```js
function processNode (node: Node) {
  return getChildrenFromServer(node.id).pipe(
    mergeMap((children: Node[]) => processNodes(children)),
    map((children: Node[]) => ({ ...node, ...children.length && { children } })),
  );
}
```

and here is where the recursion happens. Given the **children nodes** of some parent node, we repeat the process and at the end we add the `children` property to the parent node.

So, to put all the parts together:

```js
processNodes(rootNodes).subscribe(console.log)

function processNodes (nodes: Node[]): Observable<Node[]> {
  return nodes.length 
    ? forkJoin(
        nodes.map(node => node.parent ? processNode(node) : of(node))
      )
    : of([]);
}

function processNode (node: Node) {
  return getChildrenFromServer(node.id).pipe(
    mergeMap((children: Node[]) => processNodes(children)),
    map((children: Node[]) => ({ ...node, ...children.length && { children } })),
  );
}
```