# Recursive HTTP calls with RxJs to populate a tree structure

Tags: angular, http, recursion, rxjs, observable

I've the following data structure

```
export interface Node {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  children?: Node[];
}
```

I want to populate a tree composed of `Node`s with recursive HTTP calls in RxJs.

I tried the solution proposed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239316/rxjs-recursively-expand-a-tree), but I couldn't make it work. The HTTP calls are being made correclty, but the Observable does never get completed, so the subscribe doesn't get executed.

Here's the code I'm stuck with:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.getById(this.id)
     .pipe(mergeMap(s => this.getChildren(s)))
     .subscribe(res => {
        // IT NEVER GETS HERE
     });
}

getChildren(node: Node): Observable<Node> {
  return this.service.getChildren(node.id).pipe(
    mergeMap(children => forkJoin(children.map(node => this.getChildren(node)))),
    map(children => ({ ...node, children }))
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please help, thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion needs an exit criteria. You could use something like the RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif) function to enforce a condition.

In the following snippet, it is checked if the `id` property of the parameter `node` is defined.

Disclaimer: The code only presents a way to find a solution. The snippet below is untested and might not work as expected.

```js
import { Observable, forkJoin, iif, of } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.getById(this.id).pipe(
     mergeMap(s => this.getChildren(s))
  ).subscribe(
    res => {
      // handle response
    },
    error => {
      // handle errors
    }
  );
}

getChildren(node: Node): Observable<Node> {
  return iif(
    () => !!node.id,                         // <-- check if `node.id` is defined
    this.service.getChildren(node.id).pipe(  // <-- `id` property is defined
      forkJoin(children.map(node => this.getChildren(node)),
      map(children => ({ ...node, children }))
    ),
    of(node)                                 // <-- `id` property is undefined
  );
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add `mergeMap` as the first operator in the pipe right? Anyway, I tried your solution but it doesn't work. It actually completes the stream but just on the first node, so the result is just the first node itself. If i change the condition in the `iif` to `!!node.children && node.children.length > 0` I get the same original outcome I posted: the stream never gets completed